# Using jq, traverse swagger file and append each endpoint's description with the content from a lookup table where operationId acts as a key

Tags: swagger, jq, openapi

Ok, I will try my best to make it easy to understand.

So what do I have? TWO json files:

1. swagger.json (main file that needs to be modified)

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Professional",
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "Pro",
    "contact": {},
    "license": {
      "name": "Public"
    }
  },
  "host": "api.com",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/cloud/{cloud_type}/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Cloud Account Info",
        "description": "Returns top level information about the cloud account.",
        "operationId": "get-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "includeGroupInfo",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "true = Include account group info. Default is false.",
            "required": false,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CloudAccountModel"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Update Cloud Account",
        "description": "Update information related to a cloud account.",
        "operationId": "update-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Cloud Account",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "skipStatusChecks",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "true = Skip account status checks to improve response time",
            "required": false,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_account_id_format / duplicate_cloud_account_name / duplicate_cloud_account / cannot_select_zero_account_groups / invalid_account_group_ids"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_account_type"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "not_found / internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Delete Cloud Account",
        "description": "Deletes the onboarded cloud account that has the specified cloud account ID.",
        "operationId": "delete-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_cloud_type / bad_request"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "cannot_delete_org_child"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_cloud_type / invalid_account_id_format"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "patch": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Patch Cloud Account",
        "description": "Enable / disable cloud account (and children) OR Update the Account Groups it belongs to",
        "operationId": "patch-cloud-account",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Cloud Account Patch",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CloudAccountPatchModel"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_account_id_format / invalid_account_patch"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_cloud_type / invalid_account_id_format"
          },
          "405": {
            "description": "cloud_account_already_enabled / cloud_account_already_disabled"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/cloud/{cloud_type}": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Add Cloud Account",
        "description": "Onboard a new cloud account onto the Prisma Cloud platform.",
        "operationId": "add-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Cloud Account",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "skipStatusChecks",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "true = Skip account status checks to improve response time",
            "required": false,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "duplicate_cloud_account_name / duplicate_cloud_account / invalid_account_id_format / duplicate_cloud_account_needs_upgrade / cannot_select_zero_account_groups / invalid_account_group_ids"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_account_type"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/cloud/{cloud_type}/app_provisioner": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Get's terraform script/link to create Prisma Cloud App",
        "description": "Get's terraform script/link to create Prisma Cloud App",
        "operationId": "cloud-app-provisioner",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "App provisioning Params",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "default": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/login": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Login"
        ],
        "summary": "Login",
        "description": "Returns a JWT auth token for accessing the Prisma Cloud APIs.  To generate a token, you must have an access key and include the following values in the request body parameter — access key ID as the username and your secret key as the password. Prisma Cloud requires this JWT in the request header to authorize API access. Note that access keys maintain the same level of permissions as the permission group of the account that created them. ",
        "operationId": "app-login",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Model used for authentication",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/LoginModel"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/LoginResponseModel"
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "sso_enabled_password_login_attempt / invalid_credentials"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "login_failed_unknown_error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

2. endpoint-descriptions.json (look-up file)

```
{
  "update-cloud-account": {
    "path": "/cloud/{cloud_type}/{id}",
    "description": "The request body parameters differ depending on the cloud type of the account you want to add."
  },
  "app-login": {
    "path": "/login",
    "description": "If you are a multi-tenant user and the body parameters of your login request include a user name and password instead of an access key ID and secret key. "
  },
  "cloud-app-provisioner": {
    "path": "/cloud/app_provisioner",
    "description": "The payload will be variable"
  },
  "add-cloud-account": {
    "path": "/cloud",
    "description": "The request body parameters differ depending on the cloud type"
  }
}
```

What needs to be done?

I am trying to traverse the first file (swagger.json) and append each endpoint's description with the content from the look-up file (endpoint-descriptions.json) based on the operationId which acts as a key in the second file.

Here's how far I got:

```
jq -s '{"swagger": .[0], "endpoint_descriptions": .[1]}' swagger.json endpoint-descriptions.json | \
jq '.swagger | .paths[][].description |= . + $endpoint_descriptions["I do not know how to reference the proper operationId here"].description
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the second file into a variable (e.g. using `--argfile`), and reference by the appropriate key.

I assumed that the lookup result has to be added `+` with a glueing space in between `" "`. I further assumed that if the lookup yields `null` (key not present), then nothing should be added (I used the empty string `""`), i.e. the original content is being kept as-is.

```bash
jq --argfile lookup endpoint-descriptions.json '.paths[][] |= (
  .description += ($lookup[.operationId].description | " " + values // "")
)' swagger.json
```

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Professional",
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "Pro",
    "contact": {},
    "license": {
      "name": "Public"
    }
  },
  "host": "api.com",
  "schemes": [
    "https"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/cloud/{cloud_type}/{id}": {
      "get": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Cloud Account Info",
        "description": "Returns top level information about the cloud account.",
        "operationId": "get-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "includeGroupInfo",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "true = Include account group info. Default is false.",
            "required": false,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CloudAccountModel"
            }
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "put": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Update Cloud Account",
        "description": "Update information related to a cloud account. The request body parameters differ depending on the cloud type of the account you want to add.",
        "operationId": "update-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Cloud Account",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "skipStatusChecks",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "true = Skip account status checks to improve response time",
            "required": false,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_account_id_format / duplicate_cloud_account_name / duplicate_cloud_account / cannot_select_zero_account_groups / invalid_account_group_ids"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_account_type"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "not_found / internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "delete": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Delete Cloud Account",
        "description": "Deletes the onboarded cloud account that has the specified cloud account ID.",
        "operationId": "delete-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_cloud_type / bad_request"
          },
          "403": {
            "description": "cannot_delete_org_child"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_cloud_type / invalid_account_id_format"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      },
      "patch": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Patch Cloud Account",
        "description": "Enable / disable cloud account (and children) OR Update the Account Groups it belongs to",
        "operationId": "patch-cloud-account",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "id",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Account ID",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": ".+"
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Cloud Account Patch",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/CloudAccountPatchModel"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "invalid_account_id_format / invalid_account_patch"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_cloud_type / invalid_account_id_format"
          },
          "405": {
            "description": "cloud_account_already_enabled / cloud_account_already_disabled"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/cloud/{cloud_type}": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Add Cloud Account",
        "description": "Onboard a new cloud account onto the Prisma Cloud platform. The request body parameters differ depending on the cloud type",
        "operationId": "add-cloud-account",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Cloud Account",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "skipStatusChecks",
            "in": "query",
            "description": "true = Skip account status checks to improve response time",
            "required": false,
            "type": "boolean"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          },
          "400": {
            "description": "duplicate_cloud_account_name / duplicate_cloud_account / invalid_account_id_format / duplicate_cloud_account_needs_upgrade / cannot_select_zero_account_groups / invalid_account_group_ids"
          },
          "404": {
            "description": "invalid_account_type"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "internal_error"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/cloud/{cloud_type}/app_provisioner": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Cloud Accounts"
        ],
        "summary": "Get's terraform script/link to create Prisma Cloud App",
        "description": "Get's terraform script/link to create Prisma Cloud App The payload will be variable",
        "operationId": "cloud-app-provisioner",
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "App provisioning Params",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": {
                "type": "object"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "cloud_type",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Cloud Type",
            "required": true,
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "aws",
              "azure",
              "gcp",
              "alibaba_cloud",
              "oci"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "default": {
            "description": "successful operation"
          }
        },
        "security": [
          {
            "x-redlock-auth": []
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "/login": {
      "post": {
        "tags": [
          "Login"
        ],
        "summary": "Login",
        "description": "Returns a JWT auth token for accessing the Prisma Cloud APIs.  To generate a token, you must have an access key and include the following values in the request body parameter — access key ID as the username and your secret key as the password. Prisma Cloud requires this JWT in the request header to authorize API access. Note that access keys maintain the same level of permissions as the permission group of the account that created them.  If you are a multi-tenant user and the body parameters of your login request include a user name and password instead of an access key ID and secret key. ",
        "operationId": "app-login",
        "consumes": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "produces": [
          "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        ],
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "body",
            "name": "body",
            "description": "Model used for authentication",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/LoginModel"
            }
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "successful operation",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/LoginResponseModel"
            }
          },
          "401": {
            "description": "sso_enabled_password_login_attempt / invalid_credentials"
          },
          "500": {
            "description": "login_failed_unknown_error"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```